# Marklogic Data Hub Upgrade Issue

Tags: marklogic

We have been testing the upgrade process for MarkLogic Server - going from Server v9.0-8.2 to v10.0-5.2  , then the data hub going from   v4.1.1 -> v4.3.2 , then to  v5.2.6

This is running on a windows 2016 server.

Java 1.8.0_271-b09 is installed

Gradle 5.1.1 is installed

The ML server upgrade went fine.

The Data Hub upgrade from 4.1.1 to 4.3.2 went fine.

The upgrade from 4.3.2 to 5.2.6 - we have an issue, this is the commannd and the error :

gradlew.bat hubUpdate -PmlUsername= un -PmlPassword= pw -i  --debug

```
OVERALL RESULT: INSTALLED
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute updateHub for :hubUpdate'
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute updateHub for :hubUpdate' completed
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':hubUpdate'
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :hubUpdate'
12:00:29.245 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger]
12:00:29.245 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :hubUpdate FAILED
12:00:27.352 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :hubUpdate' completed
12:00:27.352 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :hubUpdate (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.696 secs.
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on :
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.9 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on root.1.9
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.696 secs, idle: 0.002 secs
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.69 secs
12:00:27.353 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.69 secs
12:00:27.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.698 secs
12:00:27.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph] Timing: Executing the DAG took 0.7 secs
12:00:27.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
12:00:27.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run tasks' completed
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
**12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':hubUpdate'.**
**12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not initialize class com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices**
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
12:00:27.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
12:00:27.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:00:27.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
12:00:27.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
12:00:27.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
12:00:27.356 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
12:00:27.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
12:00:27.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on root.1
12:00:27.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
12:00:27.356 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run build' completed


.....................................


OVERALL RESULT: INSTALLED

:hubUpdate (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 1.576 secs.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hubUpdate'.
     -->kotlin.collections.ArraysKt.copyInto([B[BIII)[B

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
.........................................
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Not sure if its a path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between the Kotlin library in Gradle and the Kotlin library in a DHF dependency. Try using the Gradle wrapper - gradlew - that is created when you initialize/upgrade a DHF project.

Comment: I discovered I had not forced the gradle wrapper to use 5.1.1 .   Once I did this the issue was resolved. I decided to keep the gradle wrapper at 5.1.1 from DH 4.1.x all the way through to 5.2.x  and this has allowed a stable upgrade path. Thank you.